# CSS3 Transition border-radius issue (Delayed on hover)

Tags: html, css-transitions, css

I am facing a problem with CSS transition, "only with border-radius"

Basically I want to animate the border, and the problem is that when I hover it takes a second before it starts to animate. I tried setting delay to 0, and it didn't work.

So is that a common problem? and if there is a solution show it to me.
If not, what is another way to do that?

Here my example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhQxV/)

some HTML code:

```
<a href=""><span  class="icon"><p>A</p></span></a>
<a href=""><span class="icon"><p>B</p></span></a>
<a href=""> <span class="icon"><p>C</p></span></a>
<a href=""> <span class="icon"><p>D</p></span></a>
```

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `border-radius`. You use:

```
border-radius: 50px;
```

You need to use half of the `width` of your element as the `border-radius`; since your element is 50px wide, use `25px` or, as noted by @david-thomas, `50%`.

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DhQxV/1/

It does not matter if you use a border radius of `100px` or `1000px`; if your width is `50px` the result is the same. However, if you animate the radius then it will affect your animation and cause delay.

Comment: I actually added 50px because I thought that 50px or more is what makes the radius circular. I should have tested. Thank you

Comment: It's worth noting that this will require changes should you change the width of the element to 60px, and again should you change back to 50px; in this case, while the answer is correct, I'd recommend explicitly using `border-radius: 50%` which automatically adapts to any changed widths.

Comment: Thank you. Seems so obvious when you know. Wasted a couple of hours of my life on this.